# Is it possible to develop a mobile OS with Cosmos?

Tags: c#, vb.net, mobile, operating-system, cosmos

Is it **possible** to develop a **mobile OS (GUI)** with [Cosmos (C# and/or VB.NET)](http://cosmos.codeplex.com)?
Do i have to add some special code or use a special compiler or something else, that it would work - or will it doesn't work with mobile devices?

Comment: Answer "probably yes", but "what steps to take to port an OS from one platform to another" feels a bit too broad for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is most probably no.  Mobile devices use different processors and system architectures (ARM, etc) and COSMOS compiles to x86/x64.  It needs to run on a PC with such a processor.  You would need to re-implement most of what COSMOS does for each platform you intended to run it on.

Comment: Just saw this answer, and honestly I think this may be the opposite of the truth. Yes, Cosmos currently only supports Intel architecture, but not only do mobile devices based on Intel exist, other architectures are specifically mentioned as a possible goal of the project. The whole point of Cosmos is to handle that *for* you, not make you reimplement it repeatedly. The largest issue would be actually handling input and such, but that does not make it impossible either. To the question "Is it **possible**..." the answer is a resounding "Yes!", regardless of how hard it may be.

Comment: @Magus it is not possible at present. It is only possible, as I said, if you want to do the legwork of extending Cosmos to support other architectures, which basically means writing the entire operating system from the ground up (meaning Cosmos gives you nothing over starting from scratch). It's possible to use MSPaint to write a Mobile OS too, if you're willing to wait for nonexistent features to eventually show up. I suppose technically you could write a Mobile OS with Cosmos, but it wouldn't run on anything but Atom, which means that your mobile OS would be useless on 98% of mobile devices.

Comment: Comparing a project that actually intends to expand to other systems to one that does not is a rather flawed argument. As is the argument that 98% == 100%, especially since 'mobile' includes tablets, where Atom is growing. The fact is, if someone wants to know whether they can experiment on something, giving an accurate answer is probably a good idea.

Comment: @Magus The strict answer to almost any "is it possible" question is yes.  Answering "yes" is therefore not really helpful.  When people are asking such questions what they are looking for are the things that complicate the yes.  So yes, you can make a mobile OS with Cosmos *except* (enter my answer) that Cosmos does not support the overwhelmingly most popular mobile architecture.  Cosmos is still struggling to get their x86 compiler straightened out.  Surely we can wait to see if they ever get around to an ARM compiler, but I personally wouldn't stake a new project on that hope.

Comment: "...most probably no." != "Yes, depending on the architecture."

Comment: @Magus Well...that's what the subsequent sentences were for.

Comment: That would be true, if they said anything of the sort. You say mobile devices use different processors. You make no mention of the fact that that is not always true. That's the whole point of all my replies.